# How can i update the content of an layout from action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to update the status of some button from an layout after i check an option in action bar menu.

I have this code for action bar menu:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            int delay = 150; // delay 150 ms.

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_disconnect:
            data.saveData(this.getApplicationContext());

                Disconnect();

            return true;
        case R.id.action_check:

            if (item.isChecked())
            {
           // here i want to update button status
                item.setChecked(false);
                ledControl.instance.data.expertMode = false;
                ledControl.instance.data.configExpertMode = 1;
                ledControl.instance.data.sendConfigTurnLightMessage();

            }
            else {
                item.setChecked(true);
                ledControl.instance.data.expertMode = true;
 // here i want to update button status
            }
                return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
            }
```

And here is layout class that controls the button is loaded as a fragment

```
public class BlinkFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Switch switch_b1, switch_b2;
        private DiscreteSeekBar discrete_bl_g, discrete_bl_h;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blink, container, false);
                    switch_b1 = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.switch_b1);
            switch_b2 = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.switch_b2);
            discrete_bl_g = (DiscreteSeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.discrete_bl_g);
            discrete_bl_h = (DiscreteSeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.discrete_bl_h);
    discrete_bl_g.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);
            discrete_bl_h.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);

    }
}
```

I have try with this kind of method:

```
        fragment = new BlinkFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is bit unclear.
I guess that you want to change BlinkFragment's view from the Activity that has ActionBar.

Following code will help you?

call the `BlinkFragment`'s methods from `YourActivity`:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private BlinkFragment getBlinkFragment() {
        return (BlinkFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int delay = 150; // delay 150 ms.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_disconnect:
                data.saveData(this.getApplicationContext());
                Disconnect();
                getBlinkFragment.onDisconnected();

                return true;
            case R.id.action_check:

                if (item.isChecked())
                {
                    // here i want to update button status
                    item.setChecked(false);
                    ledControl.instance.data.expertMode = false;
                    ledControl.instance.data.configExpertMode = 1;
                    ledControl.instance.data.sendConfigTurnLightMessage();
                }
                else {
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    ledControl.instance.data.expertMode = true;
                    // here i want to update button status
                }
                getBlinkFragment.onLedControlChanged(ledControl);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

BlinkFragment will be like below:

```
public class BlinkFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    public void onLedControlChanged(LedControl ledControl) {
        // change the view
        discrete_bl_g.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);
        discrete_bl_h.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);
    }

    public void onDisconnected() {
        // change the view
    }
}
```

Comment: what i want to do is:

Comment: i have some buttons on a fragment layout and with an check box from action bar i disable and enable the buttons, but the problem is in the layout no effect until i reload the layout.

Comment: Ok, I want to understand your problem. My code did not work in your project?